# Feedback for php code

Tags: php, mysql

hello guys I am subtracting one unit from a variable called `Eppl` which resides in a Database and this is working perfectly. However I have added a condition which is that the value of the variable `Eppl` must be greater than 0 before the subtraction takes place. My code is as follows:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `CreatedBy` AND `Eppl` FROM `events` WHERE `Eid` = '$id'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$sessionid = $row['CreatedBy'];
$notlesszero = $row['Eppl'];
$zero = 0;
//echo $result;

session_start();
if ((!($_SESSION['login_user'] == $sessionid)) && ($notlesszero>0)){

$mysqli->query("UPDATE `events` SET `Eppl` = `Eppl` - 1 WHERE `Eid` = '$id'");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `eventusers` (EventID, UserID) VALUES ('{$id}', '{$_SESSION['login_user']}')");

header("location:view.php");    
//}

}
```

The if branch works without the second condition `$notlesszero>0`...
What is the problem here?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you're looking to use a multi query here

Comment: and your first SELECT is failing you, that's why. read up on SELECT https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html and check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: `if ((!($_SESSION['login_user'] == $sessionid)) && ($notlesszero>0) && !($result($mysqli->connect_error)){...} else { echo $mysqli->connect_error};`

Comment: You are also open to SQL injections with this code. Use prepared statements, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: use a transaction, otherwise you might get de-synched if the one query fails and one succeeds. and add error handling. you're simply assuming nothing could ever possibly fail.

Comment: I'm sorry a lot of this is quite over-whelming, thank you for your advice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is wrong after you added `Eppl` to it. Fields to select should not be separated by `AND`. So

```
SELECT `CreatedBy` AND `Eppl` FROM
```

should be

```
SELECT `CreatedBy`, `Eppl` FROM
```

This is something you could have caught by inspecting the error information after executing the query, or at least by inspecting `$row` after changing the query. :-p

Comment: I was not aware that this constitutes to a mistake, thank you for pointing this out, I shall keep this in mind

Answer (score 3):

Instead of querying the database to get the value of the field and then checking it, why not just add a condition on the `UPDATE`?

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE `events` SET `Eppl` = `Eppl` - 1 WHERE `Eid` = '$id'");
```

to

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE `events` SET `Eppl` = `Eppl` - 1 WHERE `Eid` = '$id' AND `Eppl` > 0");
```

Comment: sure about the quote types?

Comment: This is the better solution.

Comment: Thank you, I shall give this a try

Comment: You're welcome. Please refer to chris85's comment though in your question concerning SQL Injection. Your code is wide open to it and you should use prepared statements like he suggested.

Comment: I am working on a hobby project of mine and have no regard for security, thank you for your concern though; I shall be sure to take a look at it later